# asp.net mvc angular jquery table not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I am new to asp.net mvc with angular and i am unable to add load jquery table.Jquery Datatable showing **No data available in table**,below is my code

**My Controller**

```
app.controller('SpaceController', function ($scope, SpaceService) {

    $scope.getAll = function () {

        loader(true);
        var getData = SpaceService.getAllData();
        getData.then(function (response) {

            if (response.data.success) {
                $scope.listdt = response.data.data;
                $('#TblID').DataTable();
                $scope.populateStatus();
                loader(false);

            }
            else {
                errorAlert("Oops", response.data.message);
                loader(false);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

**My Service**

```
app.service("SpaceService", function ($http) {


        this.getAllData = function () {
            var response = $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/Space/getAll",
                dataType: "json"
            });
            return response;
        }
});
```

**My Table html**

```
<table class="table display" id="TblID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="d in listdt">
            <td>{{d.SpaceID}}</td>
            <td>{{d.SpaceKey}}</td>
            <td>{{d.SpaceName}}</td>
            <td>{{d.SpaceDesc}}</td>
            <td> <span
                    class="label label-table {{d.StatusKey == 'A' ? 'label-success' : 'label-red'}}">{{d.StatusName}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="edit(d)"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="delete(d)"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am unable to find why it is showing **No Data**,when i try search some thing from table all got rows hide and start showing **No data available in table**.below is screen shoot.

[image]

Comment: `url: "/Space/getAll"` => is this a call to MVC controller action? Can you provide example data which returned from that action to verify search box behavior?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto,
{"data":[{"SpaceID":16,"SpaceKey":"Space - 11","SpaceName":"Space - 111","SpaceDesc":"Space - 11j","SpaceStatus":2,"StatusName":"In-active","StatusKey":"I"}],"success":true,"message":""}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixing frameworks is a notoriously bad idea.  You're using a jquery plugin to render a table generated by AngularJs.  I'm sure there are fine AngularJs components that can do something similar to DataTables.

Probably what's happening is that DOM hasn't been refreshed with rendered table data when `$('#TblID').DataTable()` is called.  So certain information isn't available when DataTables begins its rendering.  If this is correct, a hacky solution would be to call `DataTable()` inside of a `setTimeout()`:

```
getData.then(function (response) {
  if (response.data.success) {
     $scope.listdt = response.data.data;
     $scope.populateStatus();
     $timeout(function() {
        $('#TblID').DataTable();
     })
     loader(false);
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, then I recommend not having Angular render the table and passing the response to the DataTable function directly.

```
getData.then(function (response) {
  if (response.data.success) {
     $scope.listdt = response.data.data;
     $scope.populateStatus();
     $('#TblID').DataTable({
       data: response.data.data,
       columns: [
         { data: 'SpaceID', name: 'ID' },
         { data: 'SpaceKey', name: 'Key' },
         { data: 'SpaceName', name: 'Name' },
         { data: 'SpaceDesc', name: 'Description' },
         { data: 'StatusName', name: 'Status' } /* use more advanced options for style */
       ],
       buttons: [ 
         { tag: 'edit', className: 'fa fa-pencil fa-lg', action: (e, b) => $scope.edit(b.row().data()) },
         { tag: 'delete', className: 'fa fa-trash fa-lg', action: (e, b) => $scope.delete(b.row().data()) }
       ]
     });

     loader(false);
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Kindly share some good example for datatable using angular.Thanks